# Jquery UI Dialog not centered vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-ui-dialog

Question about Jquery UI Dialog. 
Got function:

```
function showOrderDetails(orderId) {
     $("#orderDetailsDiv").dialog();
}
```

Function is called like this:

```
<a href="javascript:showOrderDetails(1610);">1610</a>
```

When link is clicked, dialog appears not centered vertically on window, but on the whole page. It looks like script use page height instead of window height. Can anyone help? Jquery and jquery UI latest stable.

update: I think the problem is in DataTables, that fill table dynamicly on page load. But showOrderDetails(orderId) on anchor click, and it's possible only after DT finish loading. I can't figure out why the problem still exists.

Comment: Thought the default was centered. Did you try `position: { my: "50%", at: "50%", of: window }` ?

Comment: Could you make a [mcve]?

Comment: @Twisty same result. Yes, I got default options, but it doesn't make sense. Box is still not centered vertically.

Comment: @blgt I edited my question a little. So I have a page with table, that filled with DataTables plugin by ajax request on page load. Loaded data has anchors with function calls like in my post here.